# SQL Count number of column based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simple question here but I don't have any data to test with so I'm not sure if it is right.

Let's say I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | a       |
|       2 | a       |
|       3 | a       |
|       3 | b       |
|       4 | a       |
|       5 | a       |
|       6 | a       |
|       6 | b       |
|       6 | c       |
|       7 | a       |
+---------+---------+
```

I want to count the number of distinct items in column b for each column a.

So the result table would look like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | Count   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       2 |
|       4 |       1 |
|       5 |       1 |
|       6 |       3 |
|       7 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

How would I do this?

I've been trying something like this:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by ColumnA order by ColumnB) count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and [`COUNT` with `DISTINCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql#e-using-count-and-distinct):

```
SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) AS [Count]
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY ColumnA
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0506fd20821009e0b13010c7655e3e02)